# Select second MAX value

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

I want to select second highest value from tblTasks(JobID, ItemName, ContentTypeID)

That's what I though of. I bet it can be done easier but I don't know how.

```
SELECT Max(JobID)    AS maxjobid,
       Max(ItemName) AS maxitemname,
       ContentTypeID
FROM   
      (SELECT JobID, ItemName, ContentTypeID
      FROM tblTasks Ta
      WHERE JobID NOT IN
            (SELECT MAX(JobID)
            FROM tblTasks Tb
            GROUP BY ContentTypeID)
            ) secmax

     GROUP BY secmax.ContentTypeID
```

Comment: Second highest value of what?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you'd want something like this.

```
SELECT  JobID AS maxjobid,
        ItemName AS maxitemname,
        ContentTypeID
FROM    (SELECT JobID,
                ItemName,
                ContentTypeID,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContentTypeID ORDER BY JobID DESC) Rn
         FROM   tblTasks Ta

        ) t
WHERE Rn = 2
```

this would give you the second highest JobID record per ContentTypeID

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest `DENSE_RANK()`, if you want the second `JobID`:

```
SELECT tb.*
FROM (SELECT tb.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY JobID DESC) as seqnum
      FROM tblTasks Tb
     ) tb
WHERE seqnum = 2;
```

If there are no duplicates, then `OFFSET`/`FETCH` is easier:

```
SELECT tb.*
from tblTasks
ORDER BY JobId
OFFSET 1
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Comment: not my downvote but you ignored `GROUP BY secmax.ContentTypeID` which makes the `OFFSET/FETCH` solution a bit hard

Comment: @Aツ . . . I cannot tell what the intention is of the `GROUP BY` in the OP's query.   This way my original understanding of what the query appeared to be doing.  It is possible that the OP wants the second jobid for each content, but I'm awaiting a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can use syntax like this:

```
SELECT MAX(col)
FROM table
WHERE col < (SELECT MAX(col)
             FROM table)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tblTasks ORDER BY col DESC LIMIT 1, 1
```